# insert header and footer at tinyMCE Version 6

Tags: header, tinymce, footer, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

[image]I have installed a TinyMCE embedded in a BPMS, I have problems adding headers and footers. I tried https://github.com/sirap-group/tinymce-plugin-headersfooters without success.

Comment: I need to add headers and footers in TinyMCE, I'm working with the sirap-group plugin, it defines three Textarea work independently but I can't join them to generate a document where the header and footer are reported on all pages , when executed working independently, I require support to integrate the textarea to work as a single document.